# Django не видит модель после её перемещения в каталог models

Tags: python, django

Я переопределил модель User:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
        verbose_name = u'человека'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Люди'
```

Прописал ее в `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.Profile'
```

где `main` - название моего приложения.

В `admin.py`:

```
from .models import Profile

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

И в целом все прекрасно работало, тестилось. Заполнял тестовыми пользователями. Проблема проявилась после того, как я добавил модели для диалога в новом файле `dialogue.py` подпапки `models` моего проекта (вместе с `__init__.py`):

```
from django.db import models
from main.models import Profile

class Dialogue(models.Model):
    Partakers = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)

class Message(models.Model):
    Sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
```

Ошибка:

```
    (hello) D:\django\site\hello>d: & cd D:\django\hello\Scripts & activate.bat & cd
 D:\django\site\hello & python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x02B93B70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228,
 in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runser
ver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 251,
 in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228,
 in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup

    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in
 populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 23
, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", lin
e 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line
50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 7,
 in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 22
, in <module>
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line
 199, in get_user_model
    "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % setting
s.AUTH_USER_MODEL
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'ma
in.Profile' that has not been installed
```

Модели удалил. Потом и файл удалил. Перезапустил runserver, но ошибка осталась

Нашел в сети похожую [проблему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699598/auth-user-model-refers-to-model-that-has-not-been-installed-and-created-abstr), но так и не понял, как ее исправить

Comment: Замените изображение текстом.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, знаю, что так не принято, но я не использую ide, все запускаю из консоли, поэтому не могу просто скопировать текст ошибки. А переписывать вручную с картинки довольно долго и могу совершить опечатки, могли бы мы обойтись без этого?

Comment: Почему не можете? Из консоли текст копируется.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, точно. Скопировать получилось. Заменил текстом картинку

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, в общем путем проб и ошибок дошел до метода get_model в django.apps.config.AppConfig. При попытке получить текущую модель: self.models[model_name.lower()] получаю эту ошибку. Почему-то self.models не содержит ни одной модели. Как так может быть?

Comment: (попытался написать более конкретный заголовок, надеюсь не накосячил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы создаёте модуль `main.models` в виде каталога, то за его содержимое отвечает файл `main/models/__init__.py`.

Если файл `main/models/__init__.py` пустой, то Django не увидит никаких моделей и выдаст ошибку.

Все подмодули внутри модуля `main.models` никем не будут импортироваться автоматически; вам нужно сделать это самостоятельно. Например, если у вас есть модель `Profile` в файле `main/models/profile.py`, то в файле `main/models/__init__.py` нужно прописать что-то вроде этого:

```
import main.models.profile
```

или

```
from . import profile
```

или прописать модель явно:

```
from .profile import Profile
```

Все способы равнозначны в том смысле, что подмодуль `profile` загрузится во всех случаях и Django сможет обнаружить модель `main.Profile`, прописанную в `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

---

В какой-то момент вы пытались поместить модель `Profile` в файл `main/models/__init__.py` и получить её в файле `main/models/profile.py` примерно таким образом:

```
from main.models import Profile
```

В общем случае это не сработает, потому что скорее всего получится циклический импорт. Как я сказал выше, вам нужно подгрузить файл `profile.py` импортом вида `import main.models.profile`, но получается, что этот файл зависит от `from main.models import Profile`, но файл `__init__.py` зависит от `import main.models.profile`, но файл `profile.py` зависит от `from main.models import Profile`, но файл `__init__.py` зависит от `import main.models.profile` и так далее до бесконечности. Когда выполняется код в файле `profile.py`, код создания модели `Profile` в файле `__init__.py` банально ещё не успел выполниться — в итоге всё ломается к чертям, и `Profile` просто не обнаруживается.

Это можно решить, переместив `import main.models.profile` в самый конец файла `__init__.py` — тогда модель `Profile` успеет создасться до того, как файл `profile.py` будет загружен. Но лучше во имя чистоты архитектуры избавиться от циклических импортов и вообще не помещать никаких моделей в файл `__init__.py` и оставить там только импорты подмодулей.