# Правильная структура проекта джанго: модели

Tags: python, django

Вчера я почти 8 часов потратил на поиски банальной ошибки, описанной [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980206/auth-user-model-refers-to-model-main-profile-that-has-not-been-installed).
Проблему решил, удалив все из папки `models`, включая `__init__.py`:

То есть когда все модели находятся в файле models.py в корне проекта, то **все работает**. Когда создаю папку `models` и в ней `__init__.py`, то появляется **ошибка**, ссылку на которую я дал выше. Пробовал переносить models.py в папку `models` - ошибка та же.

Если же я пишу `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.models.Profile'`, то ругается:

> must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'." % model ValueError:
>   Invalid model reference

Как правильно организовать многофайловую структуру моделей проекта в таком случае?

Comment: А что у вас написано в файле `models/__init__.py`?

Comment: @andreymal, пусто. Ничего не писал

Comment: Ну вот в этом и причина, джанга импортирует модуль `models` — а там пусто. Испортировать все остальные файлы из каталога `models` автоматически за вас никто не будет, вам нужно прописать все нужные импорты внутри `models/__init__.py` самостоятельно

Comment: @andreymal, а как это правильно нужно делать? Я уже интуитивно пришел к тому, что надо что-то писать в `__init__.py`, но не пойму, что именно. Попробовал туда перенести саму модель Profile, но почему-то потом не могу ее оттуда импортировать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980580/Как-импортировать-класс-из-init-py

Comment: `from . import profile, users, файл3, файл4` и так далее — точно не проверял, но вроде должно работать

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо! Заработало `from .users import Profile`

Comment: На всякий случай голосую за возможный дубликат вопроса [Django не видит модель после её перемещения в каталог models](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980206/django-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d1%91-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-models) — вопросы хоть и не абсолютно одинаковые, но темы очень близкие и я там написал общий универсальный ответ