# Как импортировать класс из __init__.py

Tags: python, django

Я решил попробовать поместить часть моделей в своем джанго проекте в файл `__init__.py` папки models. Получается такая структура:

```
main
  models
    __init__.py
    users.py
  urls.py
  forms.py
  admin.py
  __init__.py
  ...
```

Так вот, поместил в `__init__.py` модель:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Можно ли ее как-то импортировать в users.py?

Пробовал

```
from . import Profile
```

говорит

> can not import Profile

Comment: `from main.models import Profile` ? А вообще структура какая-то вывернутая наизнанку, лучше уж сделать файл `models/profile.py` и импортировать `from .profile import Profile`

Comment: С учётом [вашего соседнего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980532) и моего комментария там вы вообще не сможете импортировать `__init__.py` из `users.py`, так как получится циклический импорт и всё сломается к чертям. В общем, делайте `models/profile.py` :)

Comment: @andreymal, так тоже пробовал: `from main.models import Profile`. Почему-то все равно `can not import Profile`

Comment: Ну если вы поместили его в файл `profile.py` то нужно делать `from main.models.profile import Profile`

Comment: (а если не поместили, то возможно циклический импорт всё-таки случился)

Comment: @andreymal, не-не. Он был в `__init__.py`. По идее должно было быть что-то типа `from main.models.__init__ import Profile`... Хотя, мне кажется, так не пишут. Но уже не важно: последовал вашему совету из параллельной темы

Comment: Файл `main/models/__init__.py` обозначает `main.models`, а файлы `main/models/profile.py` и подобные отвечают за модули `main.models.profile` и остальные. И в общем-то они почти никак не связаны и работают почти независимо, не считая того, что один модуль вложен внутрь другого. Если `from main.models import Profile` не работало, то скорее всего на циклический импорт нарвались

Comment: На всякий случай голосую за возможный дубликат вопроса [Django не видит модель после её перемещения в каталог models](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980206/django-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d1%91-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-models) — вопросы хоть и не абсолютно одинаковые, но темы очень близкие и я там написал общий универсальный ответ